# Database for Javafx without SQL

Tags: java, database, javafx, realm

it´s possible to use a database in JavaFX without write SQL Code?

**Obs:** A example for Android is [Realm.io](http://realm.io).

Comment: Realm doesn't work on JVM yet. :(

Comment: Yeah, I know. I am looking for anything similiar to it. Setup an mysql or sqlite is very boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is with:

**JPA + Hibernate and H2 Database.**

1. Setup JPA with modeler, so its easy to create models with annotation/Serializable. (http://jpamodeler.github.io/)

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8B764qNkc0

1. Setup Hibernate (http://hibernate.org/)
2. Setup H2 Database (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
3. Setup Persistence.xml
4. Create model classes
5. Create EntityManager

Tutorial to get it up and running: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfGDZmPj3Qw

The result is very similiar to Realm.io in Android.